# animation on button to scale down and up

Tags: html, css

I have an image tag, when the user clicks on it I want to make that image scale down and scale up with a similar animation in phone when we do long press on app icons.

What I have tried so far

```css
button:active {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

```html
<button>
 <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'/>
</button>
```

How can I achieve this any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codepen.io/helloCaptMomo/pen/QWOxQyx

I believe you can achieve it using animations, set the duration for what you think is considered a long press and then create a `@keyframes`, and use it in the `animation-name` property

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
main {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.button:active {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: expand;
  /* add this if you want it maintain its final state */
  /* animation-fill-mode:forwards; */
  /* one line */
  /* animation: expand 3s forwards;*/
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform:scale(0.5);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform:scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

html

```
<main>
  <button class="button">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200/?sig=123" />
  </button>
</main>
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the animation-name: expand ?

Comment: yes, sorry copied wrongly from my codepen

Comment: @dev, I have modified my code. let me know if you spot any more mistakes, and hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think hover will do the thing

```
button:hover {
 transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

Also if it bothers you in web view then you can use media query for this

```
@media(max-width: 767px){
   transform: scale(0.5);
   transform: scale(1.2);
   filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

Comment: Focus didn't worked

Comment: In mobile view we have to use hover to show an animation ofntapping